# Pass dynamic querystring to paypal continue page

Tags: asp.net, paypal, query-string

My website is in Asp.Net C#.

I am using paypal for my website.  i have multiple products like logo design, brochure design etc. I am using different BuyNow button for each service.

After successful payment i am sending user back to my continue.aspx page.

But I am just confused about 1 thing that are we able to receive OrderId to my continue.aspx page anyhow? I have to fetch details of that particular order on the continue.aspx page to add more design descriptions like company name, requirements etc.

Is there any way to receive my orderId as a query string on my continue.aspx after successful payment?

Comment: one more thing, may be i can store my order id in session, but when user redirects to paypal for payment and after that coming back to continue.aspx automatically from paypal, will my session expire? If not that i can surely use a session to store my orderid.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Website Payments Standard or Express Checkout?  It sounds like you are using Express Checkout, but if your using standard you may want to switch over to Express Checkout as you will have more control over the checkout flow.  With Express Checkout when the buyer is sent back to your site after they have agreed to the payment your site will perform a GetExpressCheckoutDetails API call.  You will get the buyers information with this API call.  From there you can then present the buyer with the additional options and etc before performing the DoExpressCheckoutPayment API call which is the API call that actually charges the buyer.